# LISP - remove duplicates from the given list of atoms

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to remove the duplicate occurrences of the atoms in the given list.

My code is as below -

```
(defun combine (item List)
 (if (member item List)
   List (cons item List)))

(defuneliminateDuplicates(L)
    (do
      ((M L) M)
      ((null L) M)
      (setq M (combine (car L) M))
      (setq L (cdr L))
))
```

This code works fine, it removes duplicates from the list -

```
[3]> (eliminateduplicates '(a b b c a c g a))
(G C B A)
[4]> (eliminateduplicates '(a a a a a a))
(A)
[5]> (eliminateduplicates '(a b c d))
(D C B A)
```

Here, I want the results to be in the same order as they are present in the given list.
i.e., the result of the `(eliminateduplicates '(a b b c a c g a))` should be `(B C G A)`, but not `(G C B A)`
How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: For googlers: there's the built-in [remove-duplicates](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rm_dup.htm)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest using a different approach, it's simpler and the result is as expected:

```
(defun eliminateDuplicates (L)
  (cond ((null L) L)
        ((member (car L) (cdr L))
         (eliminateDuplicates (cdr L)))
        (t (cons (car L) (eliminateDuplicates (cdr L))))))
```

For example:

```
(eliminateDuplicates '(a b b c a c g a))
=> (B C G A)
```

Comment: Better name: `eliminate-duplicates`.  Also note that there already is `remove-duplicates` in the standard.